# To Ajaxify Or Not?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, scaling

I really love the way Ajax makes a web app perform more like a desktop app, but I'm worried about the hits on a high volume site.  I'm developing a database app right now that's intranet based, that no more then 2-4 people are going to be accessing at one time.  I'm Ajaxing the hell out of it, but it got me to wondering, how much Ajax is too much?

At what point does the volume of hits, outweigh the benefits seen by using Ajax?  It doesn't really seem like it would, versus a whole page refresh, since you are, in theory, only updating the parts that need updating.

I'm curious if any of you have used Ajax on high volume sites and in what capacity did you use it?  Does it create scaling issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my current project, we do use Ajax and we have had scaling problems. Since my current project is a J2EE site that does timekeeping for the employees of a large urban city, we've found that it's best if the browser side can cache data that won't change for the duration of a user session.  Fortunately we're moving to a model where we have a single admin process the timekeeping for as many employees as possible. This would be akin to how an ERP application might work (or an email application). Consequently our business need is that the browser-side can hold a lot of data, but we don't expect the volume of hits to be a serious problem. So we've kept an XML data island on the browser-side. In addition, we load data only on an as-needed basis.

I highly recommend the book *Ajax Design Patterns* or their [site](http://ajaxpatterns.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Ajax should help your bandwidth on a high volume site if that is your concern as you are, like you said, only updating the parts that need updating. My problem with Ajax is that your site can be rendered useless if the visitors do not have javascript enabled, and most of the time I do not feel like coding the site again for non-javascript users.

Comment: With a good design, the initial site is built first then Javascript and Ajax later.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way: AJAX must not be the *only* option because of the possibility of !script, it must exist as a layer on top of an existing architecture to provide a superior experience in some regards. Given that, it is impossible for AJAX to create *more* requests or more work than simple HTML because it is handling the exact same data transfer.

Where it can save you bandwidth and server load is because AJAX provides you the ability to transfer *only* the data. You can save on redundant HTML, image, css, etc requests with every page refresh whilst providing a snappier user experience.

As **mike nvck** points out the technique of polling is a big exception to this rule, but that's about the technique not the tech: you would have the same kind of impact if you had a simple page poll.

Understand the tool and use it for what it was designed. If AJAX implementation is reducing performance, you've done something wrong.

(fwiw, my experience of profiling AJAX vs simple HTML tends to result in ~60% bandwidth, ~80-90% performance benefits)

Answer (score 1):

The most common scaling issue of ajax apps is when they are to set up to check back with the server to see if the content got updated in the meantime without the need for user actively requesting it. 5 clients checking every 10 seconds is not 5000 clients checking every 10 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax on one side reduces the server workload because it usually shows or refreshes just part of the page, while on the other side it increases number of hits to the server. I would say that all then depends of the architecture of your web application. If your application needs a lot of processing for every hit (like database access) regardless of size of the response, then Ajax will hit you a lot.